# Nested hash map with hash map

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public class HashMapsTest {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("TextFile")); // read a file 
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> words = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); // list to put the words inside 
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); // string buffer to read the file 
        String[] protasi = null;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            sb.append(sc.nextLine() + " ");
        }
        protasi = sb.toString()
                    .split("!| !|! | ! |\\? | \\?| \\? |\\?|\\.|\\. | \\.| \\."); // split the string into sentences
        String[][] leksis = new String[protasi.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < protasi.length; i++) {
            leksis[i] = protasi[i].split(" , |,| ,| ,| - |-| -|- | -- |--| --|-- | : |:| :|: | ; |;| ;|; | |    | ' |'|"
                                             + " '|' | \" |\"| \" | \"| ` |`| `|` "); // split the sentences into words
        }

        // take the table with the words and put it into a list 
        for (int i = 0; i < protasi.length; i++) {
            String x = "";
            ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < leksis[i].length; j++) {
                x = leksis[i][j];
                if (x.length() != 0) {
                    line.add(x);
                }
            }
            if (line.size() != 0) {
                words.add(line);
            }
        }

        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> outhm = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> inhm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < words.get(i).size(); j++) {
                if (!inhm.containsKey(words.get(i).get(j))) {
                    inhm.put(words.get(i).get(j), 1);
                } else {
                    inhm.put(words.get(i).get(j), inhm.get(words.get(i).get(j)) + 1);
                }
                if (!outhm.containsKey(words.get(i).get(j))) {
                    outhm.put(words.get(i).get(j), inhm);
                } else {
                    outhm.put(words.get(i).get(j), inhm);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(outhm.toString());
    }

}
```

i want to create a hashmap that return this output:

> {’man’:{’i’:3, ’am’:3, ’a’:2, ’sick’:1, ’spiteful’:1, ’an’:1,
>   ’unattractive’:1}, ’liver’: {’i’:1, ’believe’:1, ’my’:1, ’is’:1,
>   ’diseased’:1}, ... }

Instead of that output i get :

> {ails={ails=1, about=1, for=1, I=5, sick=1, believe=1, do=1, not=1,
>   and=1, me=1, unattractive=1, man=3, spiteful=1, all=1, a=2, disease=1,
>   liver=1, nothing=1, However=1, is=1, am=3, my=2, an=1, at=1, what=1,
>   diseased=1, know=2, certain=1}, about={ails=1, about=1, for=1, I=5,
>   sick=1, believe=1, do=1, not=1, and=1, me=1, unattractive=1, man=3,
>   spiteful=1, all=1, a=2, disease=1, liver=1, nothing=1, However=1,
>   is=1, am=3, my=2, an=1, at=1, what=1, diseased=1, know=2,
>   certain=1}...}

the input is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcSL4.png)

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: i wanted the output to be like that :
{’man’:{’i’:3, ’am’:3, ’a’:2, ’sick’:1, ’spiteful’:1, ’an’:1, ’unattractive’:1},
’liver’: {’i’:1, ’believe’:1, ’my’:1, ’is’:1, ’diseased’:1},
...} but instead of this i got the output above

Comment: And how does the input translate to what gets outputed?

Comment: the purpose is to read the text from a file and split into sentences, and the sentences into words. then for each word i have to put it in a hashmap with the hashmap with all the words that are in the same sentence with the word. For example if i have the text: i am a sick man. i am a spiteful man. i am an unattractive man.
I want the output to be like this: {man:{i:3,am:3, a:2, sick:1,spiteful:1, an:1, unattractive:1}

Comment: You should use [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html) instead of the `split` method in this case

Comment: it looks like you almost have it.  you are putting '=' instead of ':' in the output, and you aren't including the 'tick marks' (like those around 'tick marks').  also, you are including the word itself in its own hashmap.  looking at your expected output, I imagine you would see '{man={ails...' somewhere further down the line.  Is there an implied sort you expect to happen, or should each word be in alphabetic order?

Comment: the tick marks and the '=' are easy to fix. the point is that the way that i wrote the code i don't get different hashmap for each word and i have all the words repeated in the hashmap. i don't have any sort that i expect to happen.